# Pandas cannot plot timeseries imported from Excel

Tags: excel, pandas, matplotlib

This is my DataFrame obtained importing from an Excel .xls

```
    0   1
664     2017-12-07 19:08:54     1.1377
665     2017-12-07 19:10:31     1.1374
666     2017-12-07 19:12:17     1.1377
667     2017-12-07 19:13:28     1.1377
668     2017-12-07 19:15:25     1.1379
```

I think is correclty typed

```
0    datetime64[ns]
1           float64
dtype: object
```

However it does not plot with `ax = _df.plot()` because of some error. Any idea why?
This is my first hour in Pandas, sorry if it's classic question, but I saw only not relevant answers on this `ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1`

Thanks for your inputs

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-ca306a836171> in <module>()
----> 1 ax = _df.plot()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in __call__(self, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   2671                           fontsize=fontsize, colormap=colormap, table=table,
   2672                           yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr, secondary_y=secondary_y,
-> 2673                           sort_columns=sort_columns, **kwds)
   2674     __call__.__doc__ = plot_frame.__doc__
   2675 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in plot_frame(data, x, y, kind, ax, subplots, sharex, sharey, layout, figsize, use_index, title, grid, legend, style, logx, logy, loglog, xticks, yticks, xlim, ylim, rot, fontsize, colormap, table, yerr, xerr, secondary_y, sort_columns, **kwds)
   1898                  yerr=yerr, xerr=xerr,
   1899                  secondary_y=secondary_y, sort_columns=sort_columns,
-> 1900                  **kwds)
   1901 
   1902 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _plot(data, x, y, subplots, ax, kind, **kwds)
   1725         plot_obj = klass(data, subplots=subplots, ax=ax, kind=kind, **kwds)
   1726 
-> 1727     plot_obj.generate()
   1728     plot_obj.draw()
   1729     return plot_obj.result

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in generate(self)
    258 
    259         for ax in self.axes:
--> 260             self._post_plot_logic_common(ax, self.data)
    261             self._post_plot_logic(ax, self.data)
    262 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _post_plot_logic_common(self, ax, data)
    393             self._apply_axis_properties(ax.xaxis, rot=self.rot,
    394                                         fontsize=self.fontsize)
--> 395             self._apply_axis_properties(ax.yaxis, fontsize=self.fontsize)
    396 
    397             if hasattr(ax, 'right_ax'):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/plotting/_core.py in _apply_axis_properties(self, axis, rot, fontsize)
    466 
    467     def _apply_axis_properties(self, axis, rot=None, fontsize=None):
--> 468         labels = axis.get_majorticklabels() + axis.get_minorticklabels()
    469         for label in labels:
    470             if rot is not None:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_majorticklabels(self)
   1189     def get_majorticklabels(self):
   1190         'Return a list of Text instances for the major ticklabels'
-> 1191         ticks = self.get_major_ticks()
   1192         labels1 = [tick.label1 for tick in ticks if tick.label1On]
   1193         labels2 = [tick.label2 for tick in ticks if tick.label2On]

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in get_major_ticks(self, numticks)
   1318         'get the tick instances; grow as necessary'
   1319         if numticks is None:
-> 1320             numticks = len(self.get_major_locator()())
   1321         if len(self.majorTicks) < numticks:
   1322             # update the new tick label properties from the old

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self)
    984     def __call__(self):
    985         'Return the locations of the ticks'
--> 986         self.refresh()
    987         return self._locator()
    988 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in refresh(self)
   1004     def refresh(self):
   1005         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1006         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1007         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1008 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
    761             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    762 
--> 763         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
    764 
    765     def _get_unit(self):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    399         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    400     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 401         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    402     else:
    403         x = np.asarray(x)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    252 
    253     ix = int(x)
--> 254     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    255 
    256     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    330                 pass
    331             else:
--> 332                 return printer(obj)
    333             # Finally look for special method names
    334             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in <lambda>(fig)
    235 
    236     if 'png' in formats:
--> 237         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: print_figure(fig, 'png', **kwargs))
    238     if 'retina' in formats or 'png2x' in formats:
    239         png_formatter.for_type(Figure, lambda fig: retina_figure(fig, **kwargs))

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, **kwargs)
    119 
    120     bytes_io = BytesIO()
--> 121     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    122     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    123     if fmt == 'svg':

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, **kwargs)
   2198                     orientation=orientation,
   2199                     dryrun=True,
-> 2200                     **kwargs)
   2201                 renderer = self.figure._cachedRenderer
   2202                 bbox_inches = self.figure.get_tightbbox(renderer)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs)
    543 
    544     def print_png(self, filename_or_obj, *args, **kwargs):
--> 545         FigureCanvasAgg.draw(self)
    546         renderer = self.get_renderer()
    547         original_dpi = renderer.dpi

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in draw(self)
    462 
    463         try:
--> 464             self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
    465         finally:
    466             RendererAgg.lock.release()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   1142 
   1143             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
-> 1144                 renderer, self, dsu, self.suppressComposite)
   1145 
   1146             renderer.close_group('figure')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer, inframe)
   2424             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   2425 
-> 2426         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, self, dsu)
   2427 
   2428         renderer.close_group('axes')

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, dsu, suppress_composite)
    137     if not_composite or not has_images:
    138         for zorder, a in dsu:
--> 139             a.draw(renderer)
    140     else:
    141         # Composite any adjacent images together

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     61     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
     62         before(artist, renderer)
---> 63         draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     64         after(artist, renderer)
     65 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1134         renderer.open_group(__name__)
   1135 
-> 1136         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks(renderer)
   1137         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1138                                                                 renderer)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _update_ticks(self, renderer)
    967 
    968         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 969         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    970         if self._smart_bounds:
    971             # handle inverted limits

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    967 
    968         interval = self.get_view_interval()
--> 969         tick_tups = [t for t in self.iter_ticks()]
    970         if self._smart_bounds:
    971             # handle inverted limits

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in iter_ticks(self)
    910         Iterate through all of the major and minor ticks.
    911         """
--> 912         majorLocs = self.major.locator()
    913         majorTicks = self.get_major_ticks(len(majorLocs))
    914         self.major.formatter.set_locs(majorLocs)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in __call__(self)
    984     def __call__(self):
    985         'Return the locations of the ticks'
--> 986         self.refresh()
    987         return self._locator()
    988 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in refresh(self)
   1004     def refresh(self):
   1005         'Refresh internal information based on current limits.'
-> 1006         dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
   1007         self._locator = self.get_locator(dmin, dmax)
   1008 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in viewlim_to_dt(self)
    761             vmin, vmax = vmax, vmin
    762 
--> 763         return num2date(vmin, self.tz), num2date(vmax, self.tz)
    764 
    765     def _get_unit(self):

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in num2date(x, tz)
    399         tz = _get_rc_timezone()
    400     if not cbook.iterable(x):
--> 401         return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    402     else:
    403         x = np.asarray(x)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py in _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
    252 
    253     ix = int(x)
--> 254     dt = datetime.datetime.fromordinal(ix).replace(tzinfo=UTC)
    255 
    256     remainder = float(x) - ix

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0x118f1e978>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to plot column 1 agains column 0, i.e. the numbers against the dates? This would be done via

```
df.plot(x=0,y=1)
```

Your columns are unnamed. So you may also name them and reset the index to something useful (or as below, not so useful ;-))

```
df.columns = ["0", "1"]
df = df.set_index("0")
df.plot()
```

Both should give you a plot like the following:

[image]

Comment: the doc page http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html  reads 
`x : label or position, default None
y : label or position, default None
    Allows plotting of one column versus another` is not very clear on the mandatory setting of what to plot against what (which in my two columns case could have been obvius, but is not in general), so thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Is is not mandatory to set any parameters, as seen in the second example `df.plot()`. However, not setting any of `x` and `y` would plot both columns against the index. Actually, even in your case it should not produce any error, just produce a meaningless plot. Is my example working fine for you?

Comment: I mean the second example from the answer, where the last line is `df.plot()` but that rearanges the dataframe beforehands.